# (QGIS) Stop the Select Feature(s) tool from selecting features from a layer that have no symbology and are not visible

Tags: select

I am trying to select only the features that have a symbology but the Select Feature(s) tool is selecting everything contained within the layer, even if it is not visible on the map. Is there a way to stop this?

I would like to only highlight the features within the layer that have a symbology and are turned on in the Layers panel.

[image: Features with symbology (red line)]
[image: Features within the same layer with no symbology being selected as well]

Comment: Please specify which software you are using

Comment: While having features without symbolization might seem like a clever idea to work around selection issues, it's pretty much a disaster; you're much better off making sure that all selected features have symbology.

Comment: @Vince The layers are duplicates so I can edit Layer A and the symbology in Layer B will pop up so they are separate. It's worked in the past without me having to do anything so I'm unsure what I've changed for it to not work, but you're right - I think I'll just have an ELSE symbology to see the difference and highlight from the attribute table based on what is in the field. Thanks anyway!